# Encoded characters are not rendering correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, webforms, xss

I am using the shorthand for [HttpUtility.HtmlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx) to encode the data going into my textboxs.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProperty" runat="server" Text='<%#: Bind("Property")%>'></asp:TextBox>
```

My understanding of how encoded characters behave is that when your web browser renders them, they should display as the characters they represent and not the actual encoded characters. As this [example code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms525347(v=vs.90).aspx) on the MSDN website suggests.

However my encoded characters does not behave this way.

For example a '£' character being retrieved from a database, displays in the textbox as:

[image: £ symbol rendering incorrectly]

And not:

[image: £ symbol rendering correctly]

I don't think it has anything to do with how my website is configured to handle encoding, because if I manually set the text as the encoded characters in the HTML:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtProperty" runat="server" Text="&#163;"></asp:TextBox>
```

It renders the encoded characters correctly as:

[image: £ symbol rendering correctly]

This indicates to me that it is a problem with the way I am using HtmlEncode.

Still I tried explicitly setting the encoding to UTF-8 in my webconfig and it made no difference.

Could someone explain this behavior, or what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `<%#: Bind("Property")%>` ASP.NET will already take care of HTML-encoding the string, if you pre-encode it you'll fall in the double-encoding scenario.

See ScottGu's [New <%: %> Syntax for HTML Encoding Output in ASP.NET 4 (and ASP.NET MVC 2)](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/new-lt-gt-syntax-for-html-encoding-output-in-asp-net-4-and-asp-net-mvc-2):

> ASP.NET 4 introduces a new IHtmlString interface (along with a concrete implementation: HtmlString) that you can implement on types to indicate that its value is already properly encoded (or otherwise examined) for displaying as HTML, and that therefore the value should not be HTML-encoded again.
>
> The <%: %> code-nugget syntax checks for the presence of the IHtmlString interface and will not HTML encode the output of the code expression if its value implements this interface.
>
> This allows developers to avoid having to decide on a per-case basis whether to use <%= %> or <%: %> code-nuggets.
>
> Instead you can always use <%: %> code nuggets, and then have any properties or data-types that are already HTML encoded implement the IHtmlString interface.

Comment: <%#: Bind("Property")%> is the only point where I encode my html. Sorry, I don't understand where I am pre-encoding it?

Comment: Without seeing the code, I can't tell. Surely ASP.NET is not double-encoding the content itself, so either the content is already encoded in the source you're reading it from or something else along the way is encoding it. Have you checked by setting a breakpoint where you're filling the datasource and inspecting the data?

Comment: Using the '£' example from earlier: The unencoded  '£' character is in the database and is selected using a storedprocedure in an <asp:SqlDataSource>. This SqlDataSource is then used as the datasource for a <asp:FormView>. This FormView then contains the <%#: Bind("Property")%> where it is finally encoded. This is all done in there HTML, where there's not really any opportunity for it to be encoded until the very end.

Comment: Wait a sec, I'm a little rusty with WebForms but are you sure `<%#: Bind("Property")%>` is correct? Shouldn't it be `<%# Bind("Property")%>`? (Note the missing colon after the pound.)

Comment: Yes normally. But to encode it, I believe it needs the extra colon <%#: Bind("Property")%>. This is the point where I am finally encoding the value.

Comment: Isn't there where you're doing the double encoding? Shouldn't `<%# Bind("Property")%>` already take care of HTML-encoding the content?

Comment: Ah ha, that's it! I thought <%# didn't encoded anything, so required the extra colon to encode